# Pass .apk file as a parameter to jenkins job

Tags: android, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a two step build-pipeline in Jenkins:

1. Compile & Build project
2. Run Tests

Step-1 generates the .apk files for my android project.

In Step-2, I want to run the instrumentation tests using the emulator and the .apks from the previous step.

I know that there is a "Jenkins Parameterized Trigger Plugin": 
http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/how-to-use-jenkins-for-job-chaining-and-visualizations/

But how can I use this to pass my .apks and then use them in the emulator?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you might use the Copy Artifact Plugin. https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin

- In the upstream job you archive your apk file.
- In the downstream job you configure the Copy Artifact Plugin to retrieve the artifact archived in the upstream job.

Answer (score 0):

If you switch to Jenkins Pipeline plugin (formerly known as Workflow plugin), you can can code your pipeline stages like this:

stage 'dev'
node {
 echo 'build'
 stash includes: 'pom.xml', name: 'pom'
}
stage 'test'
node {
 echo 'test'
 unstash pom
}